# WIX - Build a setup.exe bundle which hold both 32 bit and 64 bit MSI

Tags: build, wix, windows-installer, installshield, wise

I was able to create a 32 bit and 64 bit msi of an application. Now i need to include these MSIs to a bundle like setup.exe. What is the best way to create a bundle like setup.exe that will extract the 32 bit msi in 32 bit machine and extract 64 bit msi in 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just put 2 MsiPackage elements in your bundle with mutually exclusive conditions.  VersionNT64 and Not VersionNT64.

Comment: I was able to build a bootstrapper.exe, but the problem is it is performing the full installtion by running the MSI in background. I want it to just invoke the MSI based on Platform and rest need to be performed by MSI itself.